# Problems with saving a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am new in javascript and I have a problem with writing a cookies. Here is my code

```
    function writeCookie(name, value, days){
        var cookie_expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            cookie_expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else {
    cookie_expires = "";
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + cookie_expires;

    }
```

and then if I call this function

```
function check(){
      alert("all cookies"+document.cookie);
 }
```

it gives me nothing. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these functions to write and get cookies:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
       x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
       y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
       x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
       if (x==c_name)
       {
           return unescape(y);
       }
    }
}
```